# handling duplicates and avoiding cycles when crawling the web

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler

I'm looking at [donne martin's design for a web crawler](https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer/blob/master/solutions/system_design/web_crawler/README.md).

in the "avoiding duplicates" section he describes the mechanism he thinks can be used to avoid cycles and infinite loop when crawling:

> For smaller lists we could use something like sort | unique
>
> With 1 billion links to crawl, we could use MapReduce to output only entries that have a frequency of 1

what does it mean? suppose all my crawlers maintain a `links_to_crawl` list in a redis set, and a `crawled_links` list in my hadoop. They are continually removing a new link from `links_to_crawl`, and then putting the outgoing links from that url also in `links_to_crawl`, right? when would they consult `crawled_links` with such a MapReduce job? wouldn't they need to check every link before they insert it into `links_to_crawl`? how is that a MR job?

Answer (score 0):

> we could use MapReduce to output only entries that have a frequency of 1

You don't have Redis or a set in this instance. All you have is standard "wordcount" algorithm, and you just happen to be grouping on URL and filtering out values with more than one result.

In terms of Hadoop, you can refer to the original Nutch project for web crawling

Comment: sorry, I completely fail to understand the relevance of your answer... what do you mean by "you don't have redis or a set"? this is the quoted design and the way the crawler instances are sharing the links to crawl... when do you suggest to execute a "wordcount"? by which process? on what dataset?

Comment: What DataSet - Your links to crawl? In MapReduce you cannot distribute a Set instance over mulitple JVM instances. It also doesn't use Redis unless you explicitly write it that way. As I said, you're doing classic wordcount to count `(url, "number of times it's shown")`

Comment: you have several web crawler instances working concurrently. each of them is supposed to read a bunch of urls from `links_to_crawl`, process them and add the links if discovered in them to the `links_to_crawl`. How is using a file on hadoop and doing a classic wordcount going to enable this scenario? you have to implement a queue and distribute work here, the de-duplication is just a single aspect of the problem, and I'm still not understanding how is using a file on HDFS going to solve the coordination between the services

Comment: It isn't. You'd use Zookeeper for example to implement a distributed lock and leader election per url. Besides, HDFS shouldn't be holding such a small file anyway. Unless you just have millions of urls